# Vercel CLI Pyhon version issue when deploying Django project

Tags: python, django, pip, vercel

When running the `vercel` command in Ubuntu terminal:

> Error! Command failed: python3.6 /tmp/2de7da56/get-pip.py --user

> ERROR: This script does not work on Python 3.6 The minimum supported Python version is 3.7. Please > use https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/3.6/get-pip.py instead.

`python --version` returns 3.8.10.

`pip --version` returns 22.0.4.

`vercel --version` returns 24.0.1

requirements.txt just has `Django == 4.0.3`

**What I tried:**

Ran the script linked in the error message and added its installation directory to PATH.

Updated pip in default directory to 22.0.4.

Even aliased `python3.6` to `python` at one point.

Tried on both Windows and Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same error when I recently tried to host my Django rest framework project on vercel.
I think the problem is that due to a recent update by pip the minimum version it now supports is python 3.7.

Am assuming you followed jayhale's post on Django deployment to vercel like I did. The problem is that the script in his tutorial runs on python 3.6 that's why vercel is giving out "ERROR: This script does not work on Python 3.6 The minimum supported Python version is 3.7. Please > use "https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/3.6/get-pip.py" instead."

I wrote a post about the work around I found. Just click on the link below and follow the steps in the post.

[Link](https://www.devmaesters.com/blog/15)
P.s the new script works with python 3.9

Comment: Thanks!
I was trying deploy a Django using jayhale's post. Without success!!
Using yours explanations, bingo!!

... I create a repo, only for tests Django-Vercel...
https://github.com/michelmetran/vercel-django-app

Comment: Warning: Due to `builds` existing in your configuration file, the Build and Development Settings defined in your Project Settings will not apply. Learn More: https://vercel.link/unused-build-settings

Answer (score 0):

Please add a **vercel.json** file in your project root directory, with the following configuration:

```
{
"builds": [{
    "src": "{project_name}/wsgi.py",
    "use": "@vercel/python",
    "config": { "maxLambdaSize": "15mb", "runtime": "python3.9" }
},
{
    "src": "build_files.sh",
    "use": "@vercel/static-build",
    "config": { "distDir": "staticfiles_build" }
}],
"routes": [
    {
        "src": "/static/(.*)",
        "dest": "/static/$1"
    },
    {
        "src": "/(.*)",
        "dest": "{project_name}/wsgi.py"
    }
]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).